# How to validate a form inside the bottomSheet which is included in a Scaffold?

Tags: forms, flutter, state, bottom-sheet, scaffold

I would like to validate the form inside the bottomSheet which is included in a Scaffold.

The problem is when i close the bottomSheet and click 'SAVE' (in the AppBar).

It seems final form = _formAddPlayerKey.currentState; return null when the bottomSheet is closed.

When the bottomSheet is open I can validate the form.

My code, a scaffold with a bottomSheet inside:

```
return Scaffold(

      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text('MyTitle'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          //--- Form validation
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
                  final form = _formAddPlayerKey.currentState;

              if (form.validate()) {
                form.save();

                print('SAV OK!!!');
              }
            },
            child: Text(
              'SAVE',
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .subhead
                  .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: 

          showFab
              ? FloatingActionButton(

                  child: const Icon(Icons.comment, color: Colors.white),
                  onPressed: () {
                    var bottomSheetController =
                        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet(
                      (context) => Container(
                        color: Colors.pink.withOpacity(
                            0.2), //Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                        //backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: Form(
                          key: _formAddPlayerKey,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[

                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              Container(

                                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),

                                //Colors.white,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  maxLines: 4,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 30,
                                  ),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hoverColor: Colors.white,
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    labelText: 'Observation',
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.note),
                                  ),
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  initialValue:
                                      'My observation....',
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    return validateMyValue(value);
                                  },
                                  onSaved: (value) =>
                                      _MyValue = value,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );

                    showFoatingActionButton(false);

                    /// close ?



                    bottomSheetController.closed.then((value) {
                      showFoatingActionButton(true);
                    });
                  })
              : Container(),

      bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomNavigationBar(context),
      body: _buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  void showFoatingActionButton(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      showFab = value;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define your form key globally i.e in the State class

```
var _formAddPlayerKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Whenever you want to validate your Form with that corresponding key you just need to type this,

```
bool validate = _formAddPlayerKey.currentState.validate();
```

If the boolean variable validate is true, your form is as per marks and if the validation is failed it automatically sets the error messages which you have already defined in the validate property of the TextFormField widget

Comment: Thank you for you answer (i have already define the key globally as you suggest, I will edit code) but the problem persist, when the bottonSheet is closed, when onPressed is executed (when I tap) I have this error :

Validate() is called on null... 

It seems the form inside the bottonSheet is destroyed when the bottonSheet is closed, so the form is null, the key is null and the validate() méthode of the formstate of the form is called on null....

Comment: Yes in flutter if a view is detached from the screen it destroys its current state of the view, to validate you can save the FormState on closing of the BottomSheet like this,   _formAddPlayerKey.save();

Comment: Thank you for you reply Yogesh. I did some tests, finally I've choose to not use the BottomSheet for my UI, because it wan not practice.